# How to set a javascript array based on the output of a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a MVC application that produces the following output in a browser when I visit a certain URL:

```
[{"name":"Victoria Day","date":"\/Date(1337583600000)\/"},{"name":"Canada Day","date":"\/Date(1341212400000)\/"},{"name":"Civic Holiday","date":"\/Date(1344236400000)\/"},{"name":"Labour Day","date":"\/Date(1346655600000)\/"},{"name":"Thanksgiving","date":"\/Date(1349679600000)\/"},{"name":"Remembrence Day","date":"\/Date(1352707200000)\/"},{"name":"Christmas","date":"\/Date(1356422400000)\/"},{"name":"Boxing Day","date":"\/Date(1356508800000)\/"}]
```

Of course, the source code has a bunch of html tags wrapped around that.

**How can I assign this raw information to a Javascript array?**

Comment: What do you mean with "the source code has a bunch of html tags wrapped around that"? Can you show a more detailed example?

Comment: I just mean if I fetch it with wget, it has <html><head><body>, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your http request returns the raw data that you've posted, you should be able to use:

```
var text = $.trim($(document.body).text());
var cleanedText = text.replace(/\\\/Date\(/g,"").replace(/\)\\\//g,"");
var holidays = $.parseJSON(cleanedText); // This is your array!

alert("Loaded " + holidays.length + " holidays. Fifth one is " + holidays[4].name + " celebrated on " + new Date(parseInt(holidays[4].date)).toString());

// Output(the dates should be printed with your preferred timezone offset): 
// Loaded 8 holidays. Fifth one is Thanksgiving celebrated on Mon Oct 08 2012 10:00:00 
// GMT+0300 (GTB Daylight Time)
```

If that output that you want to parse resides in other place, you should load it via jQuery in var **`text`** using your custom selector. Note that var **`cleanedText`** removes the bad characters from date values, in order to parse them as valid javascript Date objects.

Leave a comment if you have further questions. Good Luck!

​JSFiddle working example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/LtzTK/1/)

**Edit:** You need [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

**Edit2:** I think you need to use `$.get` in order to retrieve your data from a custom url(make sure it's from the same server or you might run into browser security issues). You should play a little with this and try check if your request goes to the correct path on the server(for example you can check on Google Chome browser under Developer Tools on Network tab all requests data). You should change the content of `function(data) {` to match your needs.

```
var url = 'page.html'; // You should change this with the url that returns your data.
$.get(url, function(data) {
  alert('The response is: ' + data); // Make sure it's ok
  var text = $.trim(data);
  var cleanedText = text.replace(/\\\/Date\(/g,"").replace(/\)\\\//g,"");
  var holidays = $.parseJSON(cleanedText); // This is your array!

  alert("Loaded " + holidays.length + " holidays. Fifth one is " + holidays[4].name + "           celebrated on " + new Date(parseInt(holidays[4].date)).toString());
});
```

Comment: This is perfect - except that I'm still missing step one.  I have the URL that provides the data, I'm not in the same page.  How do I use the URL to fill var text?

Comment: I've updated the post with a method to retrieve content via jQuery and Ajax from a custom url and then parse that data into array. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Get jQuery and use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), for example...

Comment: That is a terrible use for jQuery, 33kb of extra bloat just to decode a tiny bit of json is crazy.

Comment: For future reference **native JSON** [methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) `JSON.parse(jsonstring);` and `JSON.strignify(jsonobject);`. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON): _Modern browsers, such as Firefox 4 and Internet Explorer 8, include special features for parsing JSON._

Comment: As I understood from his explanation, he needed to fetch it too. There is no need to use even JSON parse if all he needed was to put it in a javascript array, it is javascript already damnit... :D And it is JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 1):

That is called [JSON](http://www.json.org/). You can use an external library like [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to parse it, or if you don't care about old browsers, use the native version,

```
var myData = JSON.parse('..data');
```

Comment: Okay thanks, this is helpful.  I feel like I'm overlooking the obvious, but how do turn the URL into '..data'?